# WSO2 identity Server: can not login?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have create a service provide use OIDC. When I login to this.'invalid_grant, Invalid authorization code received from token request' Occured. How can I change my configuration on service provide so that I can login?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a configuration issue in most of the cases and might be an issue with the token request which you send to exchange the authorization code into an access token.

Tip: You may validate whether the client id used in the `/oauth2/authorize` request is matching with the one sent in the `/oauth2/token` request.